# jQuery traversal - finding previous label to current input

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, traversal

Just a quick question as I haven't been using jQuery for that long.

Is there a neater/quicker way to get to the html for a label in this scenario.

Here is a dumbed down version as an example,

```
<tr>
   <td>
       <label>Please fill in name:</label>
   </td>
   <td>
       <input type="text" id="txtName" class="validate" />
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td>
       <label>Date of Birth:</label>
   </td>
   <td>
       <input type="text" id="txtDOB" class="validate" />
   </td>
</tr>
```

This is the jquery snippet i'm using currently to grab the html for the labels.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.validate').each(function(){
      if(!$(this).val())
      {
          var label = $(this).parent().prev().find('label').html();
          alert(label);
      }
   }); 
});
```

Any ideas are appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, there is another neat way to do so by using `Closest()` instead of `Parent()`

Consider the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.validate').each(function(){
      if(!$(this).val())
      {
          var label = $(this).closest("tr").find('label').html();
          alert(label);
      }
   }); 
});
```

[Closest()](http://api.jquery.com/closest/): *Get the first element that matches the selector, beginning at the current element and progressing up through the DOM tree.*

Comment: Beat me by 9 seconds :p haha! That's what I was going to post as well.

Comment: @Benno: LOL, I've suffered this thing many many times, Stackoverflow users are damn QUICK :)

Comment: @MohammedElSayed: Thanks, that is a little neater, which is what I was looking for really. I will accept this answer when i can as you were the fastest.

Comment: @MarkWalters: Great to hear that this is helpful for you.

Answer (score 1):

*I'll add this as an answer, even though it's a sort of diversion from your question:*

You are using table-based layout for non-tabular data, you should have layout such as

```
<div>
<label>Please fill in name:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtName" class="validate" />
</div>
<div>
<label>Date of Birth:</label>
<input type="text" id="txtDOB" class="validate" />
</div>
```

in which case the jQuery becomes super-simple:

```
$('.validate').each(function(){
      if(!$(this).val())
      {
          var label = $(this).prev('label').html();
          alert(label);
      }
   });
```

Live example: http://jsfiddle.net/MDFEm/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can a bit shorten it:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.validate').each(function(){
      if(!$(this).val())
      {
          var label = $(this).parents('tr').find('label').html(); 
          alert(label);
      }
   }); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using the 'for' attribute on the labels, not only is it semantic/accessible it gives you a shorter selector:

```
<table>
  <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="txtName">Please fill in name:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtName" class="validate" />
      </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>
        <label for="txtDOB">Date of Birth:</label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" id="txtDOB" class="validate" />
      </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

​

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.validate').each(function(){
    if(!$(this).val())
    {
      var label = $('label[for="'+$(this).attr('id')+'"]').html();
      alert(label);
    }
  }); 
});​
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative version, I do generally use the 'for' attribute on my labels. I just provided a 'no frills' example to show what i was trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

I use this;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$("select").change(function(){

if($(this).val() == "A")    
var label = $(this).parent().prev("label").text();
alert(label);

});
});
</script>
```